# JQuery plugin qTip2 - Click-to-show only works on the first element the first time

Tags: jquery, qtip2

I have a page that has some DIVs on it. I want to show a qTip2 whenever a DIV is clicked. Because of some other stuff I'm doing with the qTip I'd like to reuse the same one over and over if possible.

So, I used the qTip2 demo as a starting point and as far as I can tell I have duplicated it exactly. Here's the problem though: It only shows the qtip on the first element that's clicked - the first time. It will show on all other elements as many times as you want to click them, but the first one only the first time.

Has anyone run in to this and have a remedy?

Here's the code for a sample app I created that exhibits the problem:

CSS:

```
#Container { border: 1px solid black; }
#Container > DIV { float: left; border: 2px outset silver; margin: 5px; }
#Container > DIV:nth-last-child(1) { float: none; border: none; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; margin: -1px 0 0 0;}
```

JavaScript:

```
var Container;
var ContainerEndItem;
$(document).ready(function () {
Container = $('#Container');
if(Container.length == 0){
    alert("Container not found!");
    return;
}

var addLinks = $('.TipTarget');
$('<div>Test</div>').qtip({
            content : 'Test',
            position: {
                target: 'mouse', // Use the triggering element as the positioning target
                adjust: { mouse: false, method: 'flip' },
                my: 'left center',
                at: 'right center',
                effect: true    // Enable default 'slide' positioning animation
            },
            show: {
                target: addLinks,
                event: 'click',
                delay: 0
            },
            hide: {
                event: 'none'
            },
            events: {
                show: function (event, api) {
                    // Update the content of the tooltip on each show
                    var target = $(event.originalEvent.target);

                    if(target.length) {
                        api.set('content.text', 'Looking at: ' + target.text());
                    }
                }
            }
        });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="Container">
  <div id="Apples" class="TipTarget">Apples</div>
  <div id="Watermelons" class="TipTarget">Watermelons</div>
  <div id="Peaches" class="TipTarget">Peaches</div>
  <div id="Meat" class="TipTarget">Meat</div>
  <div id="Clear" style="clear: both">&nbsp;</div>
</div>
```

JQuery: 1.8.3

qTip2: 2.0.1

Here's a jsFiddle with this exact setup:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dracorat/Z3WqC/

Note that if you start by clicking Apple, then Watermelon, then Peaches, then Apples, then Watermelon, then Peaches, and keep repeating, that Apple will show the tip the first time only. The others will show it until the cows come home.

Note then that if you refresh and start with Watermelon, it will only show the first time, but all the rest will show each time.

What have I done wrong?

(And I have already tried using the "each" construct - it didn't change the behavior at all)

Thanks!

Comment: Another quirk I found, if you do this: `adjust: { mouse: true, method: 'flip' },` it works fine

Comment: Don't know why, but it seems that first object to be shown has its event removed (not always - if you set show `event: 'mousemove'` it seems to be working). It also works with any event if you trigger a hide event after first show: eg. http://jsfiddle.net/Z3WqC/4/

Comment: I'll look in to the memory leak (and possibly patch it myself if I'm able.) As for the other two comments, I can't have the tooltip close itself or move based on the mouse because the content I'm actually using in the tooltip is a form with form elements that updates itself based upon how the user uses the page. (That's why I'm using the same tooltip for multiple places.)

Comment: @Dracorat I am not able to reproduce the memory leak...so I dont know if thats whats affecting your code

Comment: StackErr - promote your first comment to an answer so I can accept and award bounty on it please. It prompted me to look harder at the adjust function. In doing so, I discovered that there's a logic error if (and only if) all the following three conditions are set: Target is "mouse" AND Adjust is "mouse: false" and there's no explicit hide event. The code appears to add a fake hide event that actually messes up the show event of the first object it acts upon. By changing `target: 'mouse'` to `target: 'event'` the tooltip appears beside the element rather than at the cursor but works correctly.

Comment: You can also change `position.target` to `'event'` and it will work. Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Z3WqC/6/

Comment: Which is exactly what the post right above you states.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just something I found when editing your code. If you change your code to this:

```
adjust: { mouse: true, method: 'flip' },
```

The tool tip works fine.

Comment: As pointed out, it turns out that if you have the following three things in concert: `target: 'mouse'`, `adjust: {mouse: false}` and no hide event, or a `none` hide event, then qTip2 adds a custom hide event that messes up the first show event. I was able to fix the problem by changing the target to `event`. stackErr's answer pointed me to the right direction, so I'm accepting it! Thanks!

Comment: Still, you pointed me the right direction. Besides - you can't "take back" a bounty, so I might as well award it!

Comment: @Dracorat Oh! I didn't know that about bounties. Good luck with your webpage.